# Удалить папки linux

Tags: linux, bash

Как командой в терминале linux удалить все папки и файлы ?

```
/current
  dir1
  dir2
  dir3
```

Нахожусь в папке current, ее нужно полностью очистить

Comment: Если нет названий с точками и дефисами в начале, то `rm -rfv *`

Comment: В linux нет папок.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, ох уж эти *красноглазые* линуксоиды с ЛОРа... Автор, не обращайте на таких внимания :)

Comment: @0andriy Конечно, можете не обращать. Но по факту "папки" придумал Билл Гейтс для офисного планктона, которому чужды компуктеры :)

Answer (score 4):

```
cd current/
rm -rf ./
```

команда `rm` = remove, удаляет файлы.

ключ `-r` - удалять рекурсивно

ключ `-f` - force удаление

`./` - удалить в текущей папке. Не перепутайте местами, и не напишите `/.` - потому что начнется удаление из корня системы (но вроде с какой-то версии `rm` стал умным и не позволяет просто так удалять из корня)

Comment: Ну от корня потребуется `sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /*`

Comment: @Oxyd, это смотря у кого какой корень, в chroot автоматически root, например...

Comment: @0andriy Ну --no-preserve-root по любому понадобится, даже в чруте или в каком-нить там докере.